# Can't connect Hyper-V Manager (on Windows Server 2012 R2) and Hyper-V Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

I'm with a problem to connect one Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 to one Hyper-V Manager.
The two are in the same domain. Hyper-V Manager is in DC, and I listed the administrators on Hyper-V Server and found a local Administrator that I created and the Domain Admins group.

When I try to connect Hyper-V Server to Hyper-V Manager, the following error appears: "You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer"

I've already disabled the firewall, the account I'm using has access to an administrator privilege in the domain. Could you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem a number of times. The solution that has always resolved it is to take the computer account of the computer you're running Hyper-V on and make it a local administrator on the computer you are trying to connect to. Not sure why this works, but it does.

Just to clarify, its the COMPUTER ACCOUNT, not the account of a user.

Comment: I tried everything and could not connect. I have reinstalled Hyper-V Server and now I have succeeded. Thank you for your help!